# JSON Module Error in Python on Windows 10

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-cli

I have recently installed latest `Python 3.8`, `boto3` and the latest `aws-cli` package on my PC running `Windows 10`.

I have configured aws cli and boto3 correctly as AWS commands work fine. However, when I try to read a JSON file, the Python interpreter throws an error :

```
jsonStr = json.loads(jsonVal)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\HomeUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\HomeUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\HomeUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

The code I am trying to run is given below:

```
import os
import sys
import json
import string
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

jsonVal = s3.get_object(Bucket=my_bucket, Key=my_key_path)
jsonStr = json.loads(jsonVal['Body'].read())
```

All statements prior to `json.loads()` work fine giving expected output, but fails in the `json.loads()` step. The object I am trying to retrieve is a very small document from `S3`.

Earlier, the json package used to work fine but have started throwing errors off late. It even fails to parse (`json.loads()`) other json files which it had successfully parsed in the past.

I think my json library has gone corrupt. Can anyone please identify the issue and let me know how to fix this ? Please let me know if additional information is required.

The contents of the key file is :

```
{
    "glossary": {
        "title": "example glossary",
        "GlossDiv": {
            "title": "S",
            "GlossList": {
                "GlossEntry": {
                    "ID": "SGML",
                    "SortAs": "SGML",
                    "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                    "Acronym": "SGML",
                    "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                    "GlossDef": {
                        "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                        "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                    },
                    "GlossSee": "markup"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you print out the value of the s3 key contents?  The error usually indicates the content is not valid json format or the file is blank.

Comment: @Micky Loo : i have put the contents of the object in the question above. Is there a way to fix the json module ? or do we have to clean install ?

Comment: The traceback shows the error for the line ``jsonStr = json.loads(jsonVal)``, but your code only has the line ``jsonStr = json.loads(jsonVal['Body'].read())``. Which code are you actually running?

Comment: i figured I was using the wrong json object file. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When opening your file for reading it, try encoding it like:

`jsonFile=open("Your_file.json","r",encoding="utf-8")`

then parsing it